# Why was this answer which breaks down the term america to the four root words deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

What is the reason for deleting [this answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/46379/28734) at [Since the inception of the United States, has the term "America" ever referred to something more than simply "the United States"?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/1199/since-the-inception-of-the-united-states-has-the-term-america-ever-referred-t)

Where the question specifically asks

> Would the term America have been at that time a larger concept, not
>   precisely synonymous with the United States?

the answer is affirmative: "america" can be interpreted as four words "a" "me" "ri" "ca" is four words that predate the United States by several centuries.

Do the individuals whom deleted the answer disagree with the fact that the word "america" is a combination of the four words ancient words "a" "me" "ri" "ca"?

Comment: They are certainly four syllables, and these syllables have all been found as words in ancient languages (tbh, it would probably be difficult to find a syllable that hasn't!). However, personally, I think you would need to show an example of those four words combined together, in order, as _a-me-ri-ca_ for it to be considered _the term "America"_ , which is what is asked for in the question.

Comment: @sempaiscuba It is both startling and revealing how easily persons use the word as if the word appeared from the primal ether and every person is supposed to simply accept that the word is there, without ever having researched the etymology of the word or even asked what the roots of the word are; especially at a site where the subject matter is supposedly history.

Comment: Indeed. Many have probably never even heard of Martin Waldseemüller!

Comment: @sempaiscuba The origin of the word is Ancient Egyptian. "a" (pronounced "ah" in english): pregnant; big; "me" ("meh"): pyramid; "ri" ("ree") sun; [ca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_concept_of_the_soul#Ka_(vital_spark)) ("kah", not to be confused with ["ba"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ba_(Egyptian_soul))); vital essence. Meaning "big pyramid in the sun that is alive". There are no vowels in the Ancient Egyptian alphabet, "a", "e", "i" can be substituted for any other vowel by the speaker. Note the pyramid on the US dollar and the Washington Monument (phallic vital essence).

Comment: That's certainly a novel theory. Do you have an example from any surviving Ancient Egyptian inscriptions where that sequence of hieroglyphs was used?

Comment: @sempaiscuba When one or meanings of the word is understood, from the perspective of antiquity, we can perhaps better appreciate the works of Manly P. Hall relevant to [The Secret Destiny of America](http://www.ascension-research.org/The_Secret_Destiny_of_America.html), and simultaneously set aside the western academic criticisms of [Ivan Van Sertima](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivan_Van_Sertima#Reception). This world is finite; has been traveled to and fro by two-leggeds, including before and after the continents were formed, and before the so-called "discovery" of a me ri ca.

Comment: I note the disclaimer at the top of that page states: "_Ascension Research Center does not guarantee the accuracy of any content on this site_ ..."

Comment: @sempaiscuba Whom can guarantee the absolute accuracy of anything? That is simply a link to a site containing the text of the material intended to be conveyed. Read the physical books. Draw your own conclusions. Cheers.

Comment: @sempaiscuba _"Do you have an example from any surviving Ancient Egyptian inscriptions where that sequence of hieroglyphs was used?"_ No, not yet. Consider all of the geographic locations which contain the word "ca"; several are in the western hemisphere alone. "ra" or "ri" is well known in ancient times. As to travel from the eastern to the western hemisphere (and back) in ancient times we have the Olmecs as an example; which critics of Van Sertima state were not African; the so-called ["pale" or "red head" Maori](https://youtu.be/x-HhfbCk2oU) oral history and DNA prove such travel possible.

Answer (score 8):

An assertion like that would need to be supported by evidence.

Comment: @MarkCWallace Done https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3756/why-was-this-answer-which-breaks-down-the-term-america-to-the-four-root-words-de#comment8263_3756. The onus is on the persons who use the word while ignorant of its origin and meaning. You have not demonstrated any evidence yourself that you have actually researched the word. Not doing the research for persons that use the term without actually questioning anything as to the etymology of the word is no reason whatsoever to summarily delete a valid answer to the question. You argue for pure censorship founded in ignorance.

Comment: @guest271314 If you want your non-answer to be restored, you can edit it into real (however dubious) answer by including your reasoning and evidence, and nominate it for undeletion. Soapboxing in the comments on meta will not accomplish that.

Comment: @Semaphore The answer is a real answer right now. It is not this users' fault that people simply have not looked into the meaning of a word they have been spoon-fed and yet still utterly ignore the responsibility to research the meaning of the word; they just use the word arbitrarily and expect everyone to join in their oblivious ignorance. Stop censoring content.

Comment: @Semaphore All facts are random assertions. We cannot go back in time to prove anything in "history". No answer at that question asked what the word means. They just sing along in ignorance creating secondary questions where the primary question is entirely ignored. That is their and your issue. Drops some jewels. It is up to the user to vet the idea. No matter what this user posts you people will have something to say.

Comment: @Semaphore Your reasoning is flawed. The answer contributed novel ideas to the question. Users are well suited to researching the etymology of the terms themselves. They can then draw their own conclusions. You would have something to say if this user used the word Albion to refer to a de jure name. Really do not care about what you consider "quality" or not. Am only concerned with the data, not your personality or belief system. Just the facts. Vet every fact equally, here. Take it or leave it.

Comment: @guest271314 Very well, we'll leave it deleted.

Comment: OP asserts that "America" can be interpreted as four words.  That assertion is novel, and novel interpretations require evidence.  I don't have the tools (context, historiography, etc.) to understand this answer.  I was merely asking OP to give me the tools to understand this interpretation.

Comment: @LangLangC What question and answer are you referring to?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace The context is provided in the answer itself. The word "america" is broken down into four individual words "a" "me" "ri" "ca" which comprise the single word "america". Cursory etymology of the four words confirm that each word is indeed an individual word predating the word single word "america". That is evidence. Whether you agree with that evidence or not is a separate matter altogether. The point is that persons use terms in modern times which they either 1) are not aware of the origin of the word (and do not research the term beyond modern usage); 2) defend their ignorance.

Comment: It is not evidence, any more than I can make the same assertion that the old English word "rime" derives from "ri" and "me".  If there is any stronger evidence than your assertion that this is any more than an uninteresting coincidence, you haven't presented it, and your not going to convince anyone.

Comment: @PhillS All data is evidence. Whether that evidence is valuable or not depends upon what you are investigating. Am not attempting to "convince" anyone of anything. Only relayed the raw data. Some time ago looked into the meaning of the word "america", as millions, if not billions of people use the term frequently, though few actually ask what the word means - where the word originated. Shared what found. Vet the data yourself, as any user should as to any question or answer. Draw you own conclusions following your own due diligence, within the scope that you define.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I can see, the "deleted answer":

> "america" could be interpreted as four words
>   a me ri ca
>   where the etymology of each word leads to a distinct meaning in antiquity, surviving today.

does attempt to do the following:
breaking up the word into its syllables, treating each syllable as a distinct word, with ancient origin/etymology. And ascribing each of theses syllables/"words" a nondescript meaning, "surviving to this day".

So far, so good.

But this "deleted answer" is not really an answer.

It may have been the start of an answer, even a good one? But it falls short of actually answering the question.

First, there is no explanation given to what these "ancient words" might mean, what their etymology might mean/reveal. Wheter their meaning/etymology in separation or in combination. You are the curator of your sources and references. You give us none.

> each word leads to a distinct meaning in antiquity

to which the vast majority of your readers (who are "spoon fed" the wrong ideas, as you wrote) will retort: "and this distinct meaning is: what, exactly?"

Then, I have to assume, you claim that these syllables were used way before Amerigo/Waldseemüller to refer to anything, in the conjunction as they are used now ("today"). That might be the case, I do not know either way, but we do not get any evidence for that, either. And since I already had to assume this motive, my reading might have gone off the rails already.

There is a certain contradiction in the way you claim that these small facts you present are somehow self-evident and at the same time too obscure for most people to even know and even to strange to write down in the answer?

---

If you really care about the undeletion of this question:

1. cite *and quote* your evidence, your scholarly sources or literature (if they are, ahm, let's say: "obscure"/"contrarian"/"revisionist" etc, you *have* to do that within your post. People need to be able to read and check that for themselves and obscure books are not readily available in every library or elsewhere.)
2. explain what thee syllables/words did mean in antiquity or do mean now (quotes welcome again)
3. describe, analyse, explain: how, where, when, by whom these words were connected to the very roughly interpreted frame of the question –– or whether that usage has demonstrably changed some point in time

This History:SE is a question and answer site.

In it's currently deleted form the "deleted answer" is not an answer.
All I see in this "deleted answer" is an allusion based on, well, I don't know, since this is just not a real answer (cf Semaphore's comment above), no facts, no explanation, no references, no evidence.

This site is not intended to give a reader of answers only vague incentives for a wild goose chase on some search terms. That is the job of an answer.

As stated in Mark's comment above:

> OP asserts that "America" can be interpreted as four words. That assertion is novel, and novel interpretations require evidence. I don't have the tools (context, historiography, etc.) to understand this answer. I was merely asking OP to give me the tools to understand this interpretation.

Please note: Nothing I wrote here is definitively qualifying the (possible?) content of your post on main. Whether that may end up as horrible, debatable or brilliant – or already is, I do not comment on here.  The current format and the rudiments of a methodology are just unsuitable to begin with.

Comment: _"I have to assume, you claim that these syllables were used way before Amerigo/Waldseemüller to refer to anything"_ That is correct. That was the result that deduced when researching what "america" means, as the word is used frequently, though few, if any, actually first ask what the origin of the word is. As to the critique of the answer, so be it. If the raw data is useful to you, look into the matter further, if not, simply discard the data, as this site has done. Raw data itself should not be deleted, no matter what _your_ critique is. Vet the data yourself and draw your own conclusions.